# What char should I use to replace illegal characters in a url slug

Tags: language-agnostic, seo, friendly-url

I noticed that various systems use various characters as the replacent for illegal ones in urls.

Is there a reason to use one or the other or should I just pick the one that looks best to me

The options I have seen so far include: - _ + and simply removing all illegal characters.

Comment: This question seems to summarize the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270570/special-characters-in-url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use - for space and get rid of the illegal chars (like this site is).

Also it's all lower-case.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use _ to replace illegal characters and - for space. One other option would be to simply remove the illegal characters.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Is there a reason you would do it this way or is it just a personal preference?

Comment: Using - for space seems to be rather common (as seend here at stackoverflow.com and in several blog engines). Regarding _ (or removal) for illegal characters it's only personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

My preference is "-" and I use a very simple RegEx to replace everything that I don't want.

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]*
```

This will replace any non alpha numeric characters and dash characters with a dash.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving out characters can make really strange strings. Really strange strings do not help for SEO.

The 'prettiest' solution is to transliterate your non-ascii characters to their ascii-equivalent.
This can be done using [Iconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/documentation/libiconv/iconv.1.html) (if you are on a unix platform)

You could also take a look at: [How to handle diacritics (accents) when rewriting ‘pretty URLs’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465990/how-to-handle-diacritics-accents-when-rewriting-pretty-urls)

But that is a PHP-specific question

Hope this helps